# How can I approximate numerically the $\operatorname{Erf}(x)$ function using the Fresnel integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, numerical-methods

I know that

$$C(Z)+iS(Z)=(\pi/2)^{1/2}\cdot\frac{1+i}2\cdot\operatorname{Erf}(z)$$

but I do not know how to go from here, because what I want to approximate is the real value of $\operatorname{Erf}(z)$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to format questions and answers using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, it helps to provide your thought and ideas on how to approach the problem, so we know what you've tried and where the issues are. regards

Comment: Please note that I improved your typesetting. You can have a look at the edits to see how to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will improve my typesetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand out the RHS into real and imaginary parts and get

$$C(z) + i S(z) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2} [\Re{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]-\Im{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]+ i(\Re{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]+\Im{[\text{erf}{(z)}}])  ]$$

That is,

$$2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} C(z) = \Re{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]-\Im{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]$$
$$2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} S(z) = \Re{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]+\Im{[\text{erf}{(z)}}]$$

Therefore the real part of $\text{erf}{(z)}$ is

$$\Re{[\text{erf}{(z)}]} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} [C(z)+S(z)]$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now I have the real value of a complex integral (erf(z)), but how can I approximate to erf(x) if  erf(z)=erf(  ((1+i)/(2^(1/2)))*z )

Comment: See if Formula 7.1.29 will help: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help - Ron Gordon